# Couchbase JsonObject to google JsonObject and vice versa?

Tags: gson, couchbase, json

What is the best way to convert from com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject to com.google.gson.JsonObject and vice versa ?

Answer (score 0):

Currently I am doing in the following way.

```
public RawJsonDocument put(final String key, final JsonObject  googleJsonObject) {      
    return bucket.upsert(RawJsonDocument.create(key, googleJsonObject.toString()));
}

public String get(final String key) {
    RawJsonDocument d = bucket.get(RawJsonDocument.create(key));
    if ( d != null ) {
        return d.content().toString();
    } 
    return null;
}
```

Reference : https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-convert-a-java-object-to-jsonobject-type-of-couch-base/4255

Answer (score 0):

There is another way.

```
public JsonDocument put(final String key, final JsonObject googleJsonObject) {
    try {
        JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.create(key,
                com.couchbase.client.java.document.json.JsonObject.fromJson(googleJsonObject.toString()));
        return bucket.upsert(document);
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        return null;
    }
}

public String get(final String key) {
    JsonDocument d = bucket.get(JsonDocument.create(key));
    if (d != null) {
        return d.content().toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But is slower than RawJsonDocument.

Benchmark                          Mode  Cnt       Score      Error  Units

MyBenchmark.testJsonDocument     thrpt  200   81285.574 ± 1972.377  ops/s
MyBenchmark.testRawJsonDocument  thrpt  200  148449.285 ± 3639.312  ops/s

Answer (score 0):

Another way

    `public JsonStringDocument put(final String key, final JsonObject googleJsonObject) {
        try {
            JsonStringDocument document = JsonStringDocument.create(key, googleJsonObject.toString());
            return bucket.upsert(document);
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            return null;
        }
    }`

```
public String get(final String key) {
    JsonStringDocument d = bucket.get(JsonStringDocument.create(key));
    if (d != null) {
        return d.content().toString();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This one is best of all three. But still I am looking for better option.